# Dividing, remainder and quotient

Tags: calculus

A number divided by 42 gives the quotient n and the remainder 30. Define the quotient and the remainder if we divide that number with 14.

Comment: Have you tried writing it down ?

Comment: @Hikola- Change the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we know:

$$\frac{x}{42} = n \text{ remainder } 30$$

Then

$$x = 42 \times n + 30 $$

Now divide by 14

$$x = \dfrac{42 \times n + 30}{14} = \dfrac{42 \times n}{14}+\dfrac{30}{14} = 3 \cdot n + 2 \text{ remainder } 2$$

The remainder is always 2 and the quotient is $3 \cdot n +2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 42 is divisible by 14.
So remainder will be the number after dividing 30 by 14.
Let x be the no. then
$x=42m+30$
$\Rightarrow$ $x=(14)3m+[(14*2)+2]$
$\Rightarrow$ $x=(14)(3m+2)+2$

Comment: Why would we get remainder when we devjde those 2 ?

Comment: Please answer me

Comment: @Hikola- Edited